# SwiftUI Update coordinate location constantly

Tags: swift, swiftui, mapkit

I am trying to mimic an uber-car like feature where you can see a pin constantly moving on a map.

I have a map with a pin on it. Now I can either set a loop and feed it different coordinates on a timer where I wait a second in-between coordinates.

Or is there a better way to be doing this than in the updateUIView function?

I know the coordinate should be an @State variable but where should I be changing the variable? Is there another method I should be calling and where should I call it?

```
struct ContentView: UIViewRepresentable {


func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
    MKMapView(frame: .zero)
}

func updateUIView(_ view: MKMapView, context: Context) {


    // 1
    view.mapType = MKMapType.standard // (satellite)

    // 2
    let mylocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 47.6127177,longitude: -122.1995211)

    // 3
    let runner = CLLocationCoordinate2D(
        latitude: 47.611991,longitude: -122.198849)
    let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.005, longitudeDelta: 0.005)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: mylocation, span: span)
    view.setRegion(region, animated: true)

    // 4
    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotation.coordinate = mylocation

    annotation.title = "My Location"
    
    let annotation_moving = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotation_moving.coordinate = runner
    annotation_moving.title = "ubercare"

    
    let annotations = [annotation, annotation_moving]
    view.addAnnotations(annotations)
    
    

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would be much better off creating an object/class that becomes the `Coordinator` for this type. Then you can set up a `CADisplayLink` or some other timer based mechanism to update the coordinate. But your coordinator being a class also means it doesn't get blown away each time something in the `View` hierarchy changes, which is important in your case.